# Python: Why waiting threads take so much CPU

Tags: python, multithreading, cpu

I've written a program that has a common resource "Candle Set", 5 thread agents that get candles from the candle set, call them "Workers", and another thread agent that updates the candle set, called "Candle Agent".

All threads hold on to the same `threading.Condition()`

Workflow is as follows:

Workers `wait()` on the condition until the candle agent updated the candle set. Candle agent updates candle set, does a `notifyAll()` on the condition and goes to `time.sleep()` for 5 minutes.
Meanwhile, the workers wake up, each one takes a candle from the candle set, does some action and goes back to `wait()` on the condition again.

It all seems to works fine, problem is, for some reason when all threads are in `wait()` state and the candle agent is in `time.sleep()`, the task manager of my computer shows `python` is taking up to 23%.

I also reduced the amount of workers to 1, thus having 1 worker thread and 1 candle agent thread, and still the same CPU consumption...

Why is this happening and how can I reduce the CPU consumption when there should be no thread activity? Please help...

Comment: 23% seems suspiciously close to a cpu stuck at 100% in a 4-cpu configuration... are you sure you don't have a crazy loop somewhere in your code ? Could you post a minimal working example reproducing your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! If anyone stumbles upon this in the future, check your main thread for loops! That was the bug in my case